# saving and editing serial data c#

Tags: c#, arrays, serial-port

For our school project we have to write a code in c# to read and visualize serial data from a weather station.

The code that I have now:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private SerialPort port;
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    private string buff;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnPort_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500);
        timer.Start();

        try
        {
            port = new SerialPort();                     // Create a new SerialPort object with default settings.
            port.PortName = "COM4";
            port.BaudRate = 115200;                        //  Opent de seriele poort, zet data snelheid op 9600 bps.
            port.StopBits = StopBits.One;                // One Stop bit is used. Stop bits separate each unit of data on an asynchronous serial connection. They are also sent continuously when no data is available for transmission.
            port.Parity = Parity.None;                   // No parity check occurs. 
            port.DataReceived += Port_DataReceived;
            port.Open();                                 // Opens a new serial port connection.
            buff = "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }

    private void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
        int len = port.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); // .Read --> Reads a number of characters from the SerialPort input buffer and writes them into an array of characters at a given offset.

        if (len > 0)
        {
            string str = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                if (buffer[i] != 0)
                {
                    str = str + ((char)buffer[i]).ToString();
                }
            }
            buff += str;
        }
        // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (buff != "")
            {
                textSerial.Text += buff;
                buff = "";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This code has the following output:

- Humidity: 33 %
- Temperature: 25.7 deg C
- Visible light: 112 lx
- Infrared radiation: 1802.5 mW/m2
- UV index: 0.12
- CO2: 404 ppm CO2
- Pressure: 102126 Pa

I have to store all the numbers in variables because I need to use them in my GUI.

To get all the numbers from the output :

```
public string[] convertNumbers(string inp)
    {
        string pattern = "[+-] ?\\b\\d + (\\.\\d +)?\\b";
        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
        string input = inp;

        string[] result = rgx.Split(input, 3);



        return result;

    }
```

The regex expression works fine and gives me the exact numbers.
I would like to save them into an array with 7 doubles.
What is the most efficient way to transfer the serial output into variables ?

Can somebody help me out ?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: Sorry i didn't say it right . The code for getting the serial data , to write the data in a textbox works . But writing the converted data in an extra textbox does not work

Comment: But what does this mean. What is the error you get? And what is the code you use?

Comment: I don't get any errors . And this is the code that i use

Comment: @AlessioMusone your question is not about anything to do with serial port related. This totally related to string manipulation and Regex. You should rephrase the question and its title.